# Ranger's Apprentice countries

Tags: geography, rangers-apprentice

In Ranger's Apprentice, several areas are named clearly after parts of Europe - Skandia (Scandinavia), Hibernia (Iberia), and Celtica (British isles). Is Gallica supposed to be Gaul/France?

Comment: Hibernia isn't Ireland????

Comment: Oops. Now I know. Sorry

Comment: I'd hazard a guess and say yes purely because of the regions found around it. Teutland to the North-East (Germany is to the north east of France and Germans are called Teutonics), Toscano to South East (Tuscany is to France's south east), Alpina to East (Alpine range is to France's east) and Iberion to the South West (Iberian Peninsula is to the South West of France).

Answer (score 1):

A [review of the 3rd book in the series](http://www.kidsreads.com/reviews/rangers-apprentice-book-3-the-icebound-land) says "Gallica takes both its name and its approximate language from medieval France in the age of chivalry circa 1300"

Comment: Is the reviewer someone with special (privileged) knowledge of the series?

Answer (score 1):

We get some clues from the language used in Gallica.

1. Abelard's permission phrase is "*permettez moi*", a Gallican phrase.
2. Deparnieux's castle is called "*Château Montsombre*".

Both of these phrases seem pretty French (though I'm no expert), which makes me think Gallica is France.